# Auto Incremented ID in one column whenever value changes in another column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table has a column, "Company_Name", like company_A, company_B, etc. I want another column, "Company_ID", where each company will have an integer ID starting with 1 and auto-incremented whenever company name changes.

Note that the Company_Name is not the primary key in my table. So, there will be multiple entires of a company name (and I cannot do a simple auto_increment for the company ID).

For example:

```
company_A
company_A
company_A
company_B
company_B
```

should yield

```
1
1
1
2
2
```

Comment: *"with names grouped together*" <- what does that even mean?

Comment: You want this stored permanently somewhere? Or what? Why not just make a company names table with a primary key `id` and a unique on name, then just `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` to get IDs back.

Comment: The table has several other entries too. So, I need to add one column indicating the column IDs. It will not be a primary ID, as there will be multiple entries of one company. It's a temporal data, so the time is unique in the table.

Comment: You could use an on update before trigger. Test to see if the company_name column is being changed, then increment the company_id column.

Comment: The table is already there with all the company names. Company_name column is never updated.